# how do i display this columns side by side

Tags: php

im having some problem here. basically, i want to compare columns. so i fetched object and the comparing results appeared just as expected. however, it does not return the compare value anymore after i added the fetch_array to view the current table hoping that the compare value would appear beside the compare value. is there any way i could run the compare code and make it appear the table? i tried a query but it would only work in MySQL and not PHP.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM system_audit"; $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo " ID Type Setting Value ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 

   echo  $row['ID']; 
   echo  $row['Type']; 
   echo  $row['Setting']; 
   echo  $row['Value'];       
}  

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) { 
    if($row->Setting != $row->Value) { 

        echo "X";
    } else { 
        echo "O"; 

    } 
}
```

Comment: its bad programming to loop the same array twice specially if you using a function on it while you're looping but either way could you descibe a little better what the problem is?

Comment: what `echo "";` is doing? You should read some tutorials first...

Answer (score 0):

Your code contains a lot of echo's that have no use. I would suggest learning PHP a bit more.

Your compare is wrong, this should work :

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM system_audit"; 
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

echo " ID Type Setting Value ";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
   echo $row['ID'] . "<br>"; 
   echo $row['Type'] . "<br>"; 
   echo $row['Setting'] . "<br>"; 
   echo $row['Value'] . "<br>"; 

   if($row['Setting'] != $row['Value']) { 
        echo "X" . "<br>";
    } 
    else { 
        echo "O" . "<br>";
} 
echo "<br>";
```

Comment: That's nice .. after cleaning up the mess in the posting and formatting a nice, working example, I get a down vote for not completing my post in 30 seconds. Thanks Breezer!

Comment: And the comparison was wrong, he iss comparing object vars instead of array vars.

Comment: hello guys. i am really sorry about how grossly not wonderful my code is to you guys. to be honest, i have only started learning PHP less than few weeks ago. There are many functions that i had grappled through. this is my last function. and i have no more ideas on how to do this.
AND THANK YOU JvdBerg SO MUCH! IT WORKED! You wont know how happy i am. You see the thing is, my group and i are working on this sch project. We had only decided to use PHP not long ago. So, this means alot. Really thanks!! :D